# Javascript - what does != -1 do in this function

Tags: javascript

I understand practically all of this code except the lines noted below

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1; /*?????????*/
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
    table[index] += 1;
  }
  return table;
}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
// → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

`JOURNAL` is an array. This function loops through it to find if any of the entries hold the value of pizza, and what the value of the property of `squirrel` is. Based on the results of those two checks, 1 is added to one of the 4 index in `table`. I guess I'm not understanding what the `hasEvent` function does, and how it interacts with the first `if` statement.

For more details, code can be found about halfway through this page

http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Comment: it was quicker to google it than answer... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Answer (score 5):

In JS, an array function `indexOf` returns -1 if the element you are searching the index of does not exists. It will not return 0 because 0 is a valid index.

Comment: So what does the != do at the end of the first function? Is it saying, if the index of the event isn't found, return -1? If so, why isn't it prepended with an `if` statement? Also - what causes the first `if` statement in the `tableFor` function to become true or false?

Comment: I believe you are missing some very basic programming skills, regardless of JS. `!=` is `not equal`, and returning `entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1` mean return `true` if the index of event is not equal to -1, meaning event exists.

Comment: Ok I understand now.